Connecting Next.js Frontend to Node.js Backend in AWS ECS Fargate - 404 Errors
I have developed a web app with a Next.js frontend and a Node.js backend. The app uses a PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS RDS. Both the Next.js and Node.js components are Dockerized, and everything runs perfectly on my local machine using docker-compose.
Now, I'm attempting to deploy the app on AWS ECS Fargate. Here's my setup:

I've created a VPC and configured the necessary security groups.

The Next.js app listens on port 3000.

The Node.js backend listens on port 8080, and the Next.js app makes API calls to it.

I've set up an ECS cluster and pushed my Docker images to ECR.

I've configured a Task Definition that starts both containers.

I’ve configured PostgreSQL on AWS RDS.

I’ve set up an Application Load Balancer (ALB) with:

A listener on port 80.

A target group that routes traffic to the Next.js container.




So far, I can access the homepage of the app (it lives in the Next.js app) through the ALB without any issues.
However, the problem arises when the Next.js app tries to make API calls to the Node.js backend in AWS.
Details:

Locally, in my docker-compose setup, the Node.js server environment variable (API_URL) is set to http://localhost:8080, and everything works fine.

In AWS:

I’ve tried setting API_URL to the ALB’s DNS name.

I’ve also tried setting it to http://localhost:8080 and the container name from the Task Definition http://nodejs-app:8080.

Despite these attempts, I either get 404 errors, net::ERR_FAILED, or net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when making API requests from the Next.js app to the Node.js backend.




Here is my task definition JSON file (with envs redacted and other confidential info redacted):
{
    "family": <cluster_name>,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nodejs-app",
            "image": "<ECR URI>",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "node-app-8080-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "NODE_ENV",
                    "value": "development"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "<redacted>",
                    "mode": "non-blocking",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "next-app",
            "image": "<ECR URI">,
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "next-app-3000-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 3000,
                    "hostPort": 3000,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
                    "value": <redacted>
                },
                {
                    "name": "DATABASE_URL",
                    "value": <redacted>
                },
                {
                    "name": "NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_API_URL",
                    "value": <redacted>
                },
                {
                    "name": "JWT_SECRET",
                    "value": <redacted>
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
                    "value": <redacted>
                },
                {
                    "name": "NODE_ENV",
                    "value": "development"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
                    "value": <redacted>
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "<redacted>",
                    "mode": "non-blocking",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                    "awslogs-region": "<redacted>",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "<redacted>",
    "executionRoleArn": "<redacted>",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "2048",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}

I assumed that containers within the same ECS Task Definition would share the same network, so the Next.js app should be able to communicate with the Node.js backend. However, this doesn't seem to be working.
What am I missing in this setup? How can I configure the Next.js app to communicate with the Node.js backend properly in ECS Fargate?

"I’ve tried setting API_URL to the ALB’s DNS name." That's a good first step, but that obviously isn't going to work until you add a listener to the ALB that actually forwards traffic to the API.
